# Will TCP automatically close the socket in these cases

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

We are developing a network application on linux using C/S, recently we found that the write/read on some open and connected sockets may fail when there are large amount of UDP and TCP data conveying over the bandwith, it looks like the sockets are closed by some unknown reason.

Here comes the questions, please tell me if the TCP will automatically close the sockets or not.

1. Suppose that there are a sender and a receiver, the sender sends lots of data to the receiver via a TCP non-blocking socket. And suppose there are a lot traffic on the bandwith by the application itself and other applications. 
   If the bandwith are totally deployed that the sender don't have any chance to send out the data, then will the TCP automatically close the socket in some time later? if yes, how much is the time value?
2. Suppose that the bandwith in question 1 is not fully deployed, and the sender can deliver data to the receiver successfully. But if the receiver doesn't read the data and in some time later the buffer will fill, then will TCP automatically close the socket in hours?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Did you already take a look at the network traffic with tcpdump or wireshark? Usually a socket is not closed until all data is sent and acknowledged by the other side. Also take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control

Comment: Yes, we have observed that the packets sent to the specific tcp socket  are not going out of the network card, seems that there is not enough bandwith for tcp to send out any packet. we are not sure in this case if the socket will be closed by TCP some time later, such as 1 or 2 hours later

Comment: TCP won't automatically close a socket in a running process in any cases whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of a TCP socket closing itself automatically so I doubt that is the case. In the event that the sender can't send out any data, it would just wait and try again. The only reason a socket would close is if the sender attempts to send data several time, can't, and then **explicitly** closes the socket. In the event that the sender has enough bandwidth to send out the data but the receiver lacks the bandwidth to receive it, the protocol itself will resend the data and ensure that it arrived properly (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer)).

As for #2, also from Wikipedia (as ott mentioned):

> When a receiver advertises a window size of 0, the sender stops sending data and starts the persist timer. The persist timer is used to protect TCP from a deadlock situation that could arise if a subsequent window size update from the receiver is lost, and the sender cannot send more data until receiving a new window size update from the receiver. When the persist timer expires, the TCP sender attempts recovery by sending a small packet so that the receiver responds by sending another acknowledgement containing the new window size.

Because TCP has this system in place for determining how much data to send, I assume that a TCP connection could always accept one update packet. In the situation where the buffer is still full, the receiver would continue broadcasting a window size of 0. Unless a piece of software is explicitly closing a socket after X repeated "0 window sizes," there is no reason for the socket to ever close.

Comment: Thanks sam. Regarding #2, our experiments have proved that you are right. Regarding #1, if the retransimission timeouts, then how would the tcp act? will it close the socket? or it just tells sender timeout when the sender tries to send more data? And when will it become normal

Comment: In the event that the sender is unable to send **any** packets, the receiver would not know that anything is wrong and would just assume that it has an open socket that is not actively transferring data. What would most likely happen is the sender would send a small amount of data slowly and it would just take a while. Either way, the socket would never automatically close.

Comment: @supersam64 , suppose that the traffic of the bandwith decrease dramatically in 5 hours and during the 5-hour period both the sender and the receiver don't close the TCP socket, then can we say that 

   1). after 5 hours the sender is able to write data to the same socket without getting error again?
   2). during the 5-hour period, what will happen if the sender tries to   write data to the non-blocking socket? will it return TIMEOUT error or some other error?

Comment: 1) Yes. Everything will proceed as normal. 2) It will not get acknowledgements that the data made it to the other side and will either check if the receiver can send data or try resending the data. Either way, the sender is wasting its time trying to send any meaningful amount of data during the congested period. It would be much more efficient for a network monitor to tell the sender when it should stop (and start) sending data. **Regardless**, everything will continue as planned after traffic goes down.

Comment: Thanks so much, Sam, I have learned so much from what you said. Though we haven't begun any experiment to validate the conclusion, we are greatly inspired by your comments. I will adopt your answer once the experiments support your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

While the host's TCP implementation probably do not timeout the connection even if there's no activity for a long period of time (but be aware that some TCP option exist to handle and control that behaviour, like [RFC 5482: TCP User Timeout Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5482)), most networking equipments (routers, NAT boxes, firewall, etc.) have some timeout policy where idle connection will be terminated.  Some devices have timeout values as short as 5 minutes.

So, if you are flooding your network connection with UDP, it is possible that a simultaneous TCP connection is not able to get a even a single packet out, thus resulting in the router to terminate the connection.

While TCP try to be well-behave and prevent flooding of the network link, UDP don't care at all.  So, if you can control the behaviour of the UDP traffic (either in the application or my network quality control tools), that would help your TCP traffic a lot.

Comment: 1. Regarding the 1st case, we are doing some experiments to test it, and havn't got the answer yet. But I am very surprised that routers may close the connection. As far as I know the router is only for forwarding packgets, I am not sure if it can and how it can close the connection. I will have some more tests.

Comment: 2. Regarding the 2rd case, after some experiments, I got the answer --- No, TCP won't automatically close the connection if the buffer of the receiver gets full (at least in 2.5 hours, as we tested). The reason might be like what supersam654 said.

Comment: @StevePeng Many (most?) router include some NAT functionality; idle TCP connection drop often comes from this NAT functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in my case (C Linux, kernel 3.2 in non-blocking sockets), sockets are closed automatically when receive zero bytes in recv functions and when I have a error in send -> errno = connection reset by peer. I think there are other cases (when the program receives some type specific of errors in recv and send functions). I hope that is useful for you.